# Python: how to create a function pointer with a set argument?

Tags: python, global-variables, function-pointers

My problem:

Given the following:

```
def foo(a,b)
```

I am trying to call the python 'map' function while passing in a list for 'a' but use a set value for 'b.'

Another relevant fact is that 'b' is user input and thus, I cannot use the syntax:

```
def foo(a,b='default value')
```

I want my 'map' call to look like this:

```
map(foo_wrapper,list_for_a)
```

where 'foo_wrapper' is some function that takes in 'a' but uses the user specified 'b.'

I don't know whether function pointers can be specified this way and suspect that they cannot.

My solution to this problem uses globals, so if there's a more elegant way and the above is impossible, I will mark that as the answer as well.

Here is my solution in a nutshell:

```
b = ''
def foo(a,b):
  print b,a

def foo_wrapper(a):
  foo(a,b)

def main():
  if sys.argv[1]:
    a = ['John', 'Jacob', 'Jingle all the way']
    global b
    b = sys.argv[1]
    map(foo_wrapper,a)
```

There may be a typo or two in the above; I am simplifying the problem from what I actually need to do.

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Function "pointer"?  What's a "pointer"?

Comment: Is 'procedure' the correct name? If so I will update it. I am looking up the terminology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this purpose:

```
from functools import partial

def f(a, b):
    return a + b

x = range(10)
print map(partial(f, b=3), x)
```

prints

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: functools.partial fails when trying to replace the first argument.  Try partial(f, a=3).  The lambda solution works for all replacements :)

Comment: @Foo Bah: It works with `partial(f, 3)`, which is the right solution for positional arguments anyway ;)

Comment: @Foo Bah: Omit the `a=`, and it will work.  And I still prefer it.

Comment: @delnan how about f(a,b,c) trying to specialize on b?  `functools.partial` is cool but not as general as the lambda solution

Comment: @Foo Bah; Yes, if you need something *this* fancy, you'll need to roll something (lambda or two-line `def`) yourself.

Comment: @Foo Bah: If you have `f(a, b, c)` and want to specify `b`, simply use `g = partial(f, b=2)` and call as `g(a=1, c=3)` or `g(1, c=3)`.

Answer (score 7):

You want something akin to currying.  You can just use lambda here:

```
map(lambda x: f(x,3), a)
```

Comment: And it generalizes very well :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension or a generator expression

```
[f(x, your_set) for x in your_list]
```

If you don't need a list as a result, but just a lazy evaluated iterator, you can use a generator expression (or if you meant Python 3's map).

```
(f(x, your_set) for x in your_list)
```

Edit:

For your functions that would be:

```
L = ['John', 'Jacob', 'Jingle all the way']
[foo(a, b=b) for a in L]
```

List comprehensions are a syntax sugar to replace uses of `map` with `lambda`. If you have one of the following:

```
L2 = map(lambda arg: f(arg) + arg, L1)
L2 = map(lambda (x,y): x + y, L1)
L2 = map(lambda <arg>: <expression>, L1)
```

They can be rewritten as list comprehensions:

```
L2 = [f(arg) + arg for arg in L1]
L2 = [x + y for x, y in L1]
L2 = [<expression> for <arg> in L1]
```

Generator expressions are similar, but instead of a list they return a lazy iterator, and are written with parens instead of square brackets. (And because `map` in Python 3 is changed to not return lists, there its equivalent is a generator expression.) Sometimes a list is not need, for example when you want to do:

```
','.join(map(lambda x: x.upper(), L))
```

The equivalent list comprehension is:

```
','.join([x.upper() for x in L])
```

But you actually don't need a list, so you can simply do:

```
','.join(x.upper() for x in L)
```

Comment: I tried list comprehensions, but it didn't appear to work. Could you explain your answer a bit more, perhaps?